# Converting images of alphabet to feature vector

Tags: python, ocr, feature-extraction

I want to write a python code for Persian letter recognition. I have a dataset of  Farsi alphabet that has 15 instances from each class. There are 19 classes.
Actually I don't have much experience in python. I almost know what are the steps theoretically but I dont know the coding.
Fisrt I want to convert images to feature vectors, but I don't know how to do this:/ I've searched a lot but I couldn't find anything useful.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
[image: Here is one of the images]

Comment: Hi, Did you check Feed Forward Network for Image recognition ?  or CNN for Image recognition. I am assuming this is Image recognition task. - https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers

Comment: Hi @SarweshSuman, yes it's an image recognition task something like OCR, but I dont want a NN solution, I want to do this with naive bayesian but now I want to convert the images to feature vector so that I can use these learning algorithm but I dont know how to do it?:\

Answer (score 0):

As you don't have enough data to train a deep convolutional network, I suggest you to take a look at this Python/OpenCV tutorial on a very similar dataset to yours (MNIST): https://www.learnopencv.com/handwritten-digits-classification-an-opencv-c-python-tutorial/